# Bootstrap span overflow in column after resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

col-sm-1 has a span element that class is label and col-sm-11 has a paragraph (p) on it.

[Here is fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/10532/) 
PS: Center divider needs to be pull left to reproduce the situation.

When it comes to resize, grid acts like

> - first label overlaps on col-sm-11 p
> - than label and p goes to seperate blocks

Is there any way to avoid this without changing element structure?

Any help would be appreciated

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <span class="label label-default">Lorem Ipsum </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
            <p>
                <a>Test link </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot off fiddle after resizing]

Comment: I can't see your issue in the jsfiddle there is only some divs no spans or p tags...

Comment: Take look to image on question. Lorem ipsum label overlaps to Test link

Comment: Its not clear enough to see, please edit your jsfiddle with the code you provide in your image so that we clearly understand the problem

Comment: @Mivaweb i got problem on jsfiddle, link updated

Comment: See my answer with a solution and description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You increase col-sm-2 and then fallaback to col-md-1 again so you will have more space for the samll devices for the label holder.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1">
            <span class="label label-default">Lorem Ipsum </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-11">
            <p>
                <a>Test link </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your `col-*-*` classes like this:

For middle devices use 1 col using the `col-md-1` class, for small devices you can use 2 colls using the class `col-sm-2`.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1">
            <span class="label label-default">Lorem Ipsum </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-11">
            <p>
                <a>Test link </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```